# how to use functions inner variable in python

Tags: python-3.x, function, variables

i'm doing a small script that received name from user and then search for name, if found prints his/her name otherwise print "not found".

```
def std_record():
print("1. Enter data.")
print("2. Search student")
user_input = int(input("Enter Choice: "))
if user_input == 1:
    name = input("Whats your name: ")
elif user_input == 2:
    search = input("Enter keyword: ")
    if search in name:
        print("data found: " + name +".")
    else:
        print("not found")
while True:
    std_record()
```

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'name' referenced before assignment

Comment: if my answer below was helpful, would you mind upvoting it? I'm new here and it would help me a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try initializing the name variable:

```
name = None
def std_record():
    print("1. Enter data.")
    print("2. Search student")
    user_input = int(input("Enter Choice: "))
    if user_input == 1:
        name = input("Whats your name: ")
    elif user_input == 2:
        search = input("Enter keyword: ")
        if name:
            print("data found: " + name +".")
        else:
            print("not found")
    while True:
std_record()
```

Comment: also getting the same problem in this program.

Comment: @sunnykumar Try setting name = "Blank" and checking to see if name != "Blank"

Answer (score 0):

you need to initialize strings before using them, either as an empty string or none

so name = ""
or name = None